# Keeping Data in Sync with $scope when retrieving data from an external source like a Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vzb3eLO341M48zE7mSDa

In the real world, the add function may call to an REST api to add the string to the database then return an array with, say, all the data that other users have added since last time the REST api was called. You'd have a "more complete" list than if you kept just a local synced copy of the array.

In DataService.getDataArray() we're returning a local array with defaults. That function is obviously called once, when the controller is initialized.

Since we're losing the pointer to masterArray, how do, in the angularjs fashion, let the scope know that we need basically call getDataArray again? Is this something that must be done manually? Should there be an event that the array has been updated?

I know there's lots of potential "this just works" solution but I'm only interested in the *angularjs* way to solve the problem of keeping data in sync. Data that's returned from external sources.

Comment: Could you please clarify, what do you mean by losing pointer to masterArray?

Comment: Why do you have to lose the pointer to `masterArray` ? Why don't you just update the array ?

Comment: I'm thinking it may be the cause of bugs to lose the pointer to the array. I'd like to avoid that if possible. If it's not reasonably possible then I'd rather tell team mates and myself to code under the assumption of "hey this array's pointer is very important, dont' lose it".  Many of my colleagues wouldn't realize that this would occur at all and it'll cause a lot of confusion

Comment: @bobber205: If coding properly and avoiding bugs causes confusion to your colleagues, maybe it is time to find some new colleagues ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you just want the scope to watch for changes to data in a service? You can do that using `$watch`. Additionally, if data synchronisation is a concern, you could consider polling for updates, rather than rely on updates arriving as a result of a user adding a value themselves.

For example:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService) {

    DataService.startPolling()

    $scope.$watch(function() { return DataService.getDataArray() }, function(data) {
        $scope.someData = data
    })

    $scope.addAction = function(data) {
        DataService.add(data)
    }
})

.factory("DataService", function($http, $interval) {
    var masterArray = ["0"],
        intervalID

    function pollForNewValues() {
        $http.get(...).then(response) {
            // push new values to masterArray
        }) 
    }
    function saveVal(value) {
        $http.post(...).then(response) {
            // push new values to masterArray
        })
    }
    return {
        add: function(whattoadd) {
           saveVal(whattoadd)
        },
        getDataArray: function() {
           return masterArray;
        },
        startPolling: function() {
           intervalID = $interval(function() {
              pollForNewValues()
           }, 5000)
        },
        stopPolling: function() {
           $interval.cancel(intervalID)
        }
     }
})
```

Comment: Is endless polling the data every 5 seconds really the best way? I am using this approach too in one of our sites, but when you have the site open in multiple tabs, all data is fetched for each tab and polling gets more intense. Is there no way to make this more efficient?